# Finding "T" given a Collection<T> object

Tags: c#, reflection, types

The code

```
BindingList<String> list = new BindingList<String>();
Console.WriteLine("Type: " + list.GetType());
```

produces the output

```
Type: System.ComponentModel.BindingList`1[System.String]
```

but what I want is just 'System.String'.

This question is essentially the opposite case from existing question [Get type using reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9758051/get-type-using-reflection?rq=1).

Comment: Well, it's not a string.  You got the type, you want to know the generic argument(s).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `Type.GetGenericArguments`:

```
list.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0];
```