# Asp .Net MVC on action executing - Get the value of action parameter values of user defined types on action executing

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, onactionexecuting

I want to log the each action method parameter name and its
   corresponding values in the database as key value pair. As part of
   this, I am using OnActionExecuting ActionFilterAttribute, since it
   will be the right place (OnActionExecuting method will get invoke for
   all controller action methods call) to get Action Executing context.

I am getting the value for .Net types (string, int, bool). But I am
   unable to get the value of the User defined types (custom types).
   (ex: Login model). My model might have some other nested user
   defined types as well.

I was trying to get the values of the user defined types but I am
   getting the only class name as string. I hope we can do in
   reflection.

Could you please anyone assist to resolve the issue. since I am new
   to reflection. It will helpful to me. Thanks in Advance.
   I need to get the name and value of these types in OnActionExecuting.

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    ActionParameter = new SerializableDictionary<string,string>();

    if(filterContext.ActionParameter != null)
    {
        foreach(var paramter in filterContext.ActionParameter)
        {
            //able to get returnUrl value
            //unable to get model values

            ActionParameter.Add(paramter.Key, paramter.Value);
        }
    }

}

public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
{
     return View(model);
}
```

User defined type

```
public class LoginModel
{
    public string  UserName {get;set;}

    public string  Password {get;set;}

    //User defined type

    public UserRequestBase Request {get;set;}

}   

//User defined type
public class UserRequestBase 
{
    public string  ApplicationName {get;set;}
}
```

I am able to get the value of the returnUrl (login method param) in OnActionExecuting but not for model (login method param). I am able to see the values, but don't know how to access it, I used typeof even though I am unable to get it, but I need generic because i have 20 methods in controller so I could not only for LoginModel.

Comment: You might want to take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9758051/get-type-using-reflection

Comment: As mention in the link, we need to provide the "Item"  as key for getProperty but here i coulnot know the property name in hand since it may differ for each action method. actualData.getType().getProperty("Item").PropertyType.Name;

Comment: Please anyone help on this??

Answer (score 1):

This answer isn't *exactly* what you want - based on your question - but I think it will work better for what want to accomplish. Quick aside...

Playing around with reflection and nested classes in this instance, lead to some SO (*a propos?*) errors for me...

So, a better path, maybe? Rather than trying to get/cast the property names, values (types?) from 'context.ActionParameters,` I found it was much easier to let a Json serialization do the work for me. You can then persist the Json object, then deserialize... pretty easy.

Anyway, here's the code:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json; // <-- or some other serialization entity
//...
 public class LogActions : ActionFilterAttribute, IActionFilter
    {

        // Using the example -- LoginModel, UserRequestBase objects and Login controller...

        void IActionFilter.OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
        {
            var param = (Dictionary<String, Object>)context.ActionParameters;

            foreach (var item in param.Values)
            {
                string itemName = item.GetType().Name.ToString();
                string itemToJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(item);


                // Save JsonObject along with whatever other values you need (route, etc)
            }
        }

    }
```

Then when you retrieve the Json object from the database you just have to deserialize / cast it.

```
LoginModel model = (LoginModel)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(itemToJson, typeof(LoginModel));
```

**From example:**

```
public class LoginModel
{
    public string  UserName {get;set;}

    public string  Password {get;set;}

    //User defined type

    public UserRequestBase Request {get;set;}

}   

//User defined type
public class UserRequestBase 
{
    public string  ApplicationName {get;set;}
}
```

**Controller used in example:**

```
public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
{
     return View(model);
}
```

Hope this helps. If there are further issues with this please let me know and I will try to help.